# Incrementing the value of one associative array key

Tags: php

Please how do i increment the value of a particular key in an associative array?

I doing the below but it seems not to work.
Thank you.

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = ["a" => 1, "b" => 1];
$product_id can be a or b.
   foreach ($_SESSION['cart_items'] AS $id => $quantity){
      if ($id == $product_id){
         $_SESSION[$product_id][$quantity] +=1;

      }
    }
```

Comment: `$_SESSION[$id]++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can test the code:

```
<?php

// start the session and avoid notice
@session_start();

// if not set session for cart_items, set first
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])) {
    // this is session data with product details
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array("a" => 1, "b" => 1);
}

// assuming if product is 'a'
$product_id = $_GET['product_name'];

// check if product 'a' exist in SESSION as KEY then add +1

if (isset($_SESSION['cart_items'][$product_id])) {
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$product_id]++;
}

// debug value of SESSION
echo '<pre>', print_r($_SESSION, true), '</pre>';


// run this code after save in file e.g. test.php?product_name=a or text.php?product_name=b
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][$product_id]++;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not executing anything else? $var++ increments by 1

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also do:

```
$_SESSION[$product_id] = parseInt($quantity) + 1;
```